# Get distance of element relative to its parent element

Tags: jquery

I would like to know how to get the distance/offset/position of an element relative to it's parent element.

Unlike jQuery's `position()` functionality, which get's the position relative to the parent's *offset* position, I need to get the (assuming) *stable* position of an element as it's distance from the top of the containing/parent element.

example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="pos1">Has a position of 0px from top of containing parent el.</div>
  <br style="height:20px;">
  <br style="height:20px;">
  <div id="pos2">Has a position of 40px from top of containing parent el.</div>
</div>
```

So, no matter what the position of the parent element to the document, the position of `pos1` and `pos2` would be reported the same, as they don't change relative to their parent element...

Is this possible?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This should do it:

```
$('#pos1').offset().top - $('#pos1').parent().offset().top - $('#pos1').parent().scrollTop()
```

Comment: Works; but something strange is happening for my original code base: the child offset is always changing depending on the scroll position of the parent element (which has a fixed height, that is smaller than the combined height of the children elements).

Comment: @VictorS I see, please try changing the offset() method for the position() method

Comment: Exactly! And that's why I asked the question, because the `.position()` also changes it's value for the child element depending on it's position within the scrolled parent element! WTF!

Comment: @VictorS I updated my answer. Ther are two options for you to try.

Answer (score 6):

This code works for me.

```
var child_top = $("#parent_div").scrollTop() + $("#child_div").offset().top
```

Answer (score 0):

Parent.offset() - child.offset() ?

Using jQuery offset()

Comment: if child comes after parent (in vertical positioning) then it would be Child.offset() - Parent.offset() right?

Comment: Yes you are right, just take the idea of taking both relative to document.